# Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting https://172.28.68.39:13000//v3

Tags: client, openstack-keystone

I have an issue with our `openstack` client to access openrc.sh in `openstack` with error below.

As I read `openstack` guide, it says that I should include `OS_CACERT` but our customer does not want to give the path in their horizon but instead give us the certs, `ca.crt` and `undercloud.crt.`

I don’t know how to include this in my openrc.sh. `OS_AUTH_URL=https://172.28.68.39:13000` is the actual value when I download from their horizon.

I have edited and tried so many ways but could not passed this identity checking.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Please.

```
ubuntu@openstackcli:\~$ cat openrc.sh

export OS_NO_CACHE=True

export COMPUTE_API_VERSION=1.1

export OS_USERNAME=MVRTB_user

export no_proxy=,172.28.68.39,172.28.94.51

export OS_REGION_NAME=regionOne

export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default

export OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=3

export OS_CLOUDNAME=overcloud

export OS_AUTH_URL=https://172.28.68.39:13000//v3

export NOVA_VERSION=1.1

export OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=2

export OS_PASSWORD=MVRuser123

export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default

export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3

export OS_PROJECT_NAME=MVRTB

export OS_AUTH_TYPE=password

export PYTHONWARNINGS='ignore:Certificate has no, ignore:A true SSLContext object is not available'

ubuntu@openstackcli:\~$ . openrc.sh

ubuntu@openstackcli:\~$ openstack
```

(openstack) image list

Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting [https://172.28.68.39:13000//v3](https://172.28.68.39:13000/v3). Attempting to parse version from URL.

Could not find versioned identity endpoints when attempting to authenticate.

Please check that your `auth_url` is correct.

```
SSL exception connecting to [https://172.28.68.39:13000//v3] 
(https://172.28.68.39:13000/v3): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.28.68.39', 
port=13000): Max retries exceeded with url: //v3 (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error(\[('SSL routines', 
'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')\])")))
```

(openstack)

‘’’

Adding `//v3 or /v3 on OS*AUTHURL` does not work. Also added `OS*\_CACERT` and pointed to certs in our `vm` not helping also

Comment: It was solved after I got updated ca cert from Openstack team. Put it in a folder in our vm and point it there in OS_CACERT=/home/xxxx/ca.cert.pem